# How to see the whole picture in mplab ipe?

Tags: mplab

I'm using MPLABX IPE 1.95 on linux. For some reason the programmers decided to make the main window non-resizeable.

[image]

So it's impossible to see the memory view properly. If the memory view isn't open, I can't even see the bottom of the output window.

Is there any trick to make the window the right size?
Otherwise, can someone perhaps give the developers monitors that are larger than 640x480?

I hope the **status** isn't important

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem. A workaround is to right-click in the **Output** or **Memory View** window and select **`Undock`** from the context menu. From my experience, the *Status* is not important. It shows the progress of the configuration changes when in *Advanced Mode*.